# Fix bad MoCap retargeting (pose offset) in context - UE5.1

Tags: unreal-engine5

I've got many minutes of mocap data captured onto a Metahuman skeletal mesh asset coming in as FBX into Unreal. Because of some bad retargeting issues upstream, all the animations have the same offset problems: knees bend, hands a bit warped, shoulders too far back etc.

I believe I can fix this using a custom metahuman-to-metahuman retargeter where I just compensate for the incorrect bone rotations.

The problem I'm having is that I haven't found a way to correct these poses in context (ie: viewing a frame of the animation that shows the issue and then rotating the bones to fix it). It seems Unreal wants you to edit a POSE. But the A-Pose that I get is perfect looking. There's nothing to fix. It's only when you pplay an animation do you see the issues. If I go to edit a bone, it pops back to the perfect pose so I can only guess at the offsets, play the animation, rinse and repeat. It's very tedious.

What's the solution?

I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76466179/467386) that is based on the theory that if I can create a variety of Pose Assets using different frames from my animation, I should be able to create those offset poses more easily, but if there's an even better way, I'd like to hear about it!