# Create pose asset that matches a particular animation frame - UE5.1

Tags: unreal-engine5

In an [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76466078/467386) question I'm looking for a workflow to fix bad animation retargeting in-context, but here's a more specific question relating to Poses in Unreal Engine 5.1.

I'm trying to "freeze" an animation at a specific frame and capture a POSE asset from that exact frame, so I can later use that pose asset in my retargeting workflow.

There is a tutorial that's easily found that shows how to capture a single-frame animation, and there are also ways to bake a static mesh from an animation frame, but I want to create a pose asset from an animation frame.

It seems obvious - you scrub an animation to the frame you want and then choose "Create Pose Asset" from Current Animation, but that just results in another perfect A-Pose, not a pose based on the current frame of the animation.

Is it just not possible (and why the heck not). Or am I missing the point of Poses altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is a bit of a weird one but the solution appears simple enough. Once you have created the pose asset from an animation frame as mentioned above, you have to edit the pose asset and find the Weight slider and set it to 1.0 and then re-save the asset.

I have no idea why this last step is necessary, but it seems to work. Then you can re-import the pose asset into your retargeter and make it a retarget pose.